# Is there anyway to connect to IRC server via Message app?

Tags: macos, messages, irc

I'm wondering is there anyway to connect to IRC server via Message default app in OS X. Could I do it over XMPP protocol?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No the Messages app won't work as an IRC client. You have to use another app. [Here](http://www.irchelp.org/irchelp/clients/mac/) you can find a list of good apps supporting IRC.

Comment: Hi NEO, I already use Adium as my IRC client. This question contains my hope for using default OSX app for IRC because default OSX app is the best for performance...

Comment: I myself have used Adium for years and it's really good. Yeah I see your point but the Messages app does not support IRC.